# How do I scan into a 2d char array without scanning in the enter/space chars?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, chars

So I have to make a maze program, and to start I must scan in the maze to a 2d array. The problem arises when i go to put the chars into the array, when the enter char and the space char always take up the first slot in the array...

Here is my code:

```
    int main(){

    int row, col;

    int i,j,k,l;

    scanf("%d", &row);

    scanf("%d", &col);

    char** maze = (char**) calloc(row, sizeof(char*));

    for ( k = 0; k < row; k++ )
    {
        maze[k] = (char*) calloc(col, sizeof(char));
    }

    for(i=0;i<row;i++){

        for(j=0;j<col;j++){

            scanf("%c",&maze[j][i]);

        }

    }

    for(k=0;k<row;k++){

        for(l=0;l<col;l++){

            printf("%c", maze[k][l]);

        }

        printf("\n");

    }


   return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

With the enter char:

3

3

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xx

xxx

xxx

With a space:

3

3 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xx

xxx

xxx

without any thing: (this one works)

3

3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxx

xxx

xxx

Comment: @user3121023, this works... thanks! I had no idea that that was even a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so as [user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3121023/user3121023) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044429/how-do-i-scan-into-a-2d-char-array-without-scanning-in-the-enter-space-chars/36044704#comment59737510_36044429), putting a space before the `%c` in
`scanf(" %c",&maze[j][i]);` works!

> The space before the % will skip leading whitespace such as space and enter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getchar()` and retry on `'\n'`. `scanf()` seems an overkill.

```
for(i=0;i<row;i++){

    for(j=0;j<col;j++){

        while ( '\n' == (maze[j][i]=getchar() ) );

    }

}
```